How can I make a table width 100% for Safari/Firefox Reader Mode?
On browsers like Safari and Firefox, the table width isn't shown 100% in Reader View Mode. But if I add <table width="100%">, HTML validators flag it as an obsolete element. Adding styles won't work as Reader View Mode strips CSS. Tried using inline styles for the table but that too is stripped away in Reader View Mode.
How to resolve this issue?
My code for table:


<table width="100%">
    <caption>The table below shows nutritional values per serving without the additional fillings.</caption>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Calories</td><td>227kcal</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Carbs</td><td>0g</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Protein</td><td>20g</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Fat</td><td>22g</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>




how about using a CSS class?

width is an attribute, not an element.

This is the problem I'm having. CSS styles can't be used and the width property on tables is obsolete.

Just checked in Google Chrome, using a CSS class will do the trick, for example:
.tbl_reader {
    width: 100%;
}

and of course, don't forget to add the class="tbl_reader" to the table tag.

Reader Mode on browsers strips away any styles applied using CSS. So the width needs to be directly applied to the HTML element without CSS.

Reader mode in Chrome supports external CSS. Have you checked?

You can use colgroup tag. The colgroup is very useful to apply styles to all columns in table. I provide updated code using colgroup.
<table>
    <caption>The table below shows nutritional values per serving without the additional fillings.</caption>
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width: 50%">
        <col style="width: 50%">
    </colgroup>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Calories</td><td>227kcal</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Carbs</td><td>0g</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Protein</td><td>20g</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Fat</td><td>22g</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


Reader Mode on browsers strips away any styles applied using CSS. So the width needs to be directly applied to the HTML element without CSS.

You can add a class to the table and width: 100% to the class.
This should solve.
<table class="table">
<caption>The table below shows nutritional values per serving without the additional fillings.</caption>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Calories</td><td>227kcal</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Carbs</td><td>0g</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Protein</td><td>20g</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Fat</td><td>22g</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>

CSS:
.table { width: 100%; }

Also, the width attribute is deprecated.
A simple google search -

The width attribute, now deprecated, was once the correct way to
adjust the width of a table's columns.


Reader Mode on browsers strips away any styles applied using CSS. So the width needs to be directly applied to the HTML element without CSS.

In that case you can apply inline css using style attribute;
eg: 
or you can have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30661650/how-does-firefox-reader-view-operate

I tried that too, mate. Doesn't work. Reader Mode removes all styles. So this has to be done without CSS. I imagine only using HTML.
