# Optimize website to show reader view in Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-reader-view

Firefox 38.0.5 added a "Reader View" to the address bar:

[image]

But not all sites get this icon, It only appears when readable content page is detected. So how do I **enable** this for my site?

I tried media print and an extra stylesheet for print-view, but that has no effect:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
  @media print { /* no effect: */
    .no-print { display:none; }
  }
</style>
<!-- no effect either:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" media="print"><!--  -->
</head><body>
<h1>Some Title</h1>
<img class="no-print" src="http://dummyimage.com/1024x100/000/ffffff&text=This+banner+should+vanish+in+print+view">
<br><br><br>This is the only text
</body></html>
```

---

What code snippets do I have to add into my website sourcecode so this **book icon** will become visible to the visitors of my site?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Does Firefox Reader View Operate (FF version 38.0.5)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30661650/how-does-firefox-reader-view-operate-ff-version-38-0-5)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to add `<div>` or `<p>` tags to achieve a page to iniciate the ReaderView.

I created a simple html that works:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Reader View shows only the browser in reader view</title>
</head>

<body>
  Everything outside the main div tag vanishes in Reader View<br>
  <img class="no-print" src="http://dummyimage.com/1024x100/000/ffffff&text=This+banner+should+vanish+in+print+view">
  <div>
    <h1>H1 tags outside ot a p tag are hidden in reader view</h1>
      <img class="no-print" src="http://dummyimage.com/1024x100/000/ffffff&text=This+banner+is resized+in+print+view">
  <p>
     123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
     123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
     123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
     123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
     123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
     123456789 123456
    </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This is the minimum needed to activate it. This is a somewhat multi-faceted process where scores are added for text chunks.

You can for example activate the reader view in forum's software if you add a `<p>`-tag around each message block in the view-posts template.

[Here are some more details about the mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30688312/1069083)

Comment: Does this still apply? I tried it and it does not trigger Firefox ReaderView option. Are there any other criteria? Like the page not being local or something?

Comment: @FanaticD if by local you mean a `file:///` URL, correct. Reader Mode isn't offered for file browsing even on compatible HTML.

Comment: Note that the `file:///` exclusion was originally done "for security reasons" (related to concerns about sites linking `about:reader?url=file:///` URLs to do nefarious things), and now that that's been solved in other ways last word was that the Mozilla team were "open to revisiting" the `file:///` URL issue. But that was over a year ago, and no revisiting has yet occurred. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1166829

Answer (score 21):

As the code stands in [May '20](https://github.com/mozilla/readability/blob/52ab9b5c8916c306a47b2119270dcdabebf9d203/Readability-readerable.js#L44) the trigger function (`isProbablyReaderable`) scores only `p` or `pre` elements and `div` elements that contain at least one decedent `br`.

A slight oversimplification of the scoring heuristic is:

- For each element in ['p', 'pre', 'div > br']:

  - If `textContent` length is > 140 chars, increase `score` by `sqrt(length - 140)`
- if cumulative `score` > 20, return `true`

Comment: based on this I created a small js snipped that shows I'm by far over this limit. but firefox is not showing a reader mode icon.

Comment: @iRaS Was the page in the file system or hosted?
Did you found out the cause?

Comment: @surfmuggle yes, that was the reason: the button gets only active for pages requested via http.