# How to trigger Firefox reading mode?

Tags: html, firefox

I'm trying to make reader mode work in my page, so I decided to wrap article around `<article>` tag, and then add some paragraphs and headers. But for some reason Firefox reading mode doesn't shows up on my page. I know that code should be semantic, but I think my code is semantic enough to pass.

```html
<article>
  <h1>About me</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque asperiores, accusamus nostrum illo commodi ea harum laudantium temporibus. Non, debitis. Omnis rem maiores corrupti nulla saepe modi suscipit quibusdam veniam! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto, consequatur. Modi officia corporis error beatae commodi exercitationem ratione molestias accusantium quae, itaque est fugiat similique sit, recusandae nobis architecto incidunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
    adipisicing elit. Porro eligendi consequatur voluptas magnam quaerat sint temporibus ipsam iusto sit. Magni culpa doloribus molestias quidem provident expedita sunt dolores commodi tempora? Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
    Molestias neque distinctio praesentium eveniet? Perspiciatis delectus, obcaecati, molestias labore rem necessitatibus veritatis aliquid dolorem repellendus accusantium reprehenderit distinctio quos, sunt ea. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur,
    adipisicing elit. Sed veritatis voluptatem beatae suscipit porro maxime vel laudantium, numquam perspiciatis neque voluptatibus in natus recusandae dignissimos ex modi nostrum. Culpa, qui. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex
    aut quaerat facere quod, incidunt id quo, illo sequi pariatur ut est! Explicabo nostrum eum provident omnis, odio aut eos reiciendis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Fugit sed ad maiores similique. Et sequi, error quo deleniti
    unde aut esse ratione vitae tempora maxime debitis saepe. Sed, illo quo! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui ullam distinctio ut itaque, recusandae temporibus beatae tenetur fugiat. Sint, enim eos facilis eveniet rem quo
    dolorem. Excepturi soluta consequuntur tempora. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet fugit a amet ducimus consequatur tenetur, voluptatibus recusandae molestias ratione sed maiores soluta laborum voluptate veniam natus
    quasi. Maxime, nemo pariatur. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic iure possimus sapiente ratione inventore numquam accusantium dolorum veniam ex aspernatur ab dolorem sunt qui deserunt, porro deleniti rerum, necessitatibus
    earum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi soluta, minima maiores cupiditate aspernatur eveniet ad nulla dolore tempore rerum veritatis vero debitis quae repudiandae. Harum, voluptate culpa. Ad, placeat. Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab neque voluptas nihil saepe dolores, earum quia odit sequi repellat animi illum delectus quos inventore quod fugit accusantium impedit labore unde! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet
    libero aliquid at, tempore similique adipisci cum recusandae aspernatur, dicta pariatur, impedit hic natus optio ea aperiam totam facere alias voluptas? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum </p>
  <h1>Another text</h1>
  <p>
    culpa similique laboriosam labore earum voluptate deleniti ea id impedit exercitationem incidunt, iste, facilis minima eius et temporibus corrupti, quisquam ducimus! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam perferendis porro accusamus
    impedit temporibus repellat, corporis cum? Dolore labore pariatur non officiis itaque blanditiis, velit quia quam adipisci sapiente repudiandae! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque asperiores, accusamus nostrum illo commodi
    ea harum laudantium temporibus. Non, debitis. Omnis rem maiores corrupti nulla saepe modi suscipit quibusdam veniam! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto, consequatur. Modi officia corporis error beatae commodi exercitationem
    ratione molestias accusantium quae, itaque est fugiat similique sit, recusandae nobis architecto incidunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro eligendi consequatur voluptas magnam quaerat sint temporibus ipsam iusto sit.
    Magni culpa doloribus molestias quidem provident expedita sunt dolores commodi tempora? Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias neque distinctio praesentium eveniet? Perspiciatis delectus, obcaecati, molestias labore rem
    necessitatibus veritatis aliquid dolorem repellendus accusantium reprehenderit distinctio quos, sunt ea. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Sed veritatis voluptatem beatae suscipit porro maxime vel laudantium, numquam perspiciatis
    neque voluptatibus in natus recusandae dignissimos ex modi nostrum. Culpa, qui. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex aut quaerat facere quod, incidunt id quo, illo sequi pariatur ut est! Explicabo nostrum eum provident omnis,
    odio aut eos reiciendis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Fugit sed ad maiores similique. Et sequi, error quo deleniti unde aut esse ratione vitae tempora maxime debitis saepe. Sed, illo quo! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    adipisicing elit. Qui ullam distinctio ut itaque, recusandae temporibus beatae tenetur fugiat. Sint, enim eos facilis eveniet rem quo dolorem. Excepturi soluta consequuntur tempora. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet
    fugit a amet ducimus consequatur tenetur, voluptatibus recusandae molestias ratione sed maiores soluta laborum voluptate veniam natus quasi. Maxime, nemo pariatur. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic iure possimus sapiente
    ratione inventore numquam accusantium dolorum veniam ex aspernatur ab dolorem sunt qui deserunt, porro deleniti rerum, necessitatibus earum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi soluta, minima maiores cupiditate aspernatur
    eveniet ad nulla dolore tempore rerum veritatis vero debitis quae repudiandae. Harum, voluptate culpa. Ad, placeat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab neque voluptas nihil saepe dolores, earum quia odit sequi repellat animi
    illum delectus quos inventore quod fugit accusantium impedit labore unde! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet libero aliquid at, tempore similique adipisci cum recusandae aspernatur, dicta pariatur, impedit hic natus optio
    ea aperiam totam facere alias voluptas? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum culpa similique laboriosam labore earum voluptate deleniti ea id impedit exercitationem incidunt, iste, facilis minima eius et temporibus corrupti,
    quisquam ducimus! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam perferendis porro accusamus impedit temporibus repellat, corporis cum? Dolore labore pariatur non officiis itaque blanditiis, velit quia quam adipisci sapiente repudiandae!
  </p>
</article>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Firefox reader view operate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30661650/how-does-firefox-reader-view-operate)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a duplicate of the question:

### [Optimize website to show reader view in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30730300/optimize-website-to-show-reader-view-in-firefox)

---

If anyone is looking for how to force-enable Reader Mode (e.g. through a Firefox extension), then you can use this comand:

`browser.tabs.toggleReaderMode()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/toggleReaderMode

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30661650/how-does-firefox-reader-view-operate