# What conditions cause Chrome simplified view prompt?

Tags: google-chrome, mobile

Some of the pages on the site I'm building cause chrome to prompt simplified view when viewed on mobile. These pages specifically seem to be the ones with more content (just more text and images than the others). Simplified view spoils the website look so ideally none of the pages would prompt this but I can't find a list of what could be causing the prompt in order to deal with it.

As a guess it may be possible that there is a word count above which the prompt loads or perhaps the greater amount of content is a red herring and there's another cause.

I found this Stack Overflow solution but unfortunately my text size was already larger than the answer recommended and so wasn't of help in this case:
[Prevent show simplified view prompt or work with simplified view on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50588116/prevent-show-simplified-view-prompt-or-work-with-simplified-view-on-chrome/50682854)

Thanks in advance for any assistance on this

Comment: Update, experimenting I've found adding more/less text to a paragraph does affect whether the prompt appears. Whether this is to do with the length of the page, the word count specifically or something else I'm still unclear

Any advice on how to avoid the prompt in either case would be amazing

Answer (score 3):

I have experimented with the total word count, number of images, number of 'p' elements and length of page. The prompt is incurred if there are more than a certain number of text elements but that those elements each have to have a minimum amount of text.

Pages with few elements containing large volumes of text do not cause the prompt but neither do pages with many elements with little text, only pages with a certain number of elements with no less than a certain number of words cause the prompt to appear.

This seems to be the problem with the pages at fault on my site. Since I didn't want to change the volume of text on the pages I instead replaced the `<p>` elements with `<div>` elements which solved the problem, definitely not the most proper way to do it though.